# Featured image broken / not displaying in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

There is a free download template that I liked and installed on my Wordpress site.

*This template is the HR Game Pro.*

- *Demo Link: http://demo.themevina.com/hr_gamepro*
- *Download Link: https://www.themevina.com/hr-game-pro/*

  - my website: http://jatekok.cc

This template **supports the featured image function**, which works perfectly on the demo page **but does not show me** the featured images.

For posts, I can add a featured image, but it does not appear on my home page (and nowhere else), only a "**broken image**" icon appears.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wumbs.png)

Looking at the source code of the "broken image" icon, **the link to the image leads to the homepage of my site** (jatekok.cc) rather than the driect featured image link.

I can not figure out what that is.

I install the theme on any server, the same problem exists, so the bug is in the HR Game Pro template. Unfortunately I can not contact the Wordpress template developer, so I would like to ask for help. :)

If one of you approached me and would help me, please look at the theme of what's causing the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Demo and Download link both links are taking to 404 page your question needs bit more clarity as i can see code of your post its showing home URL its mean something is wrong with the code with your theme not with demo as you are saying its showing alright on demo.

Please paste code chunk of your post so that we could help you with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I apologize.
The regular links:
demo: http://demo.themevina.com/hr_gamepro
download: https://www.themevina.com/hr-game-pro/
Thank you very much for dealing with the subject